# How can I fix a corrupted world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one

I have a Minecraft world that I have worked on for a year and it has become corrupted.

I have tried resetting my Xbox One and it still doesn't work.

Is there anything I can do to make the world playable again?

Answer (score 1):

Prehaps try to make a copy of the world, and try to load up the world using the copy.

Back on Legacy Xbox One Edition, I had a corrupted world and copying it seemed to be the only thing that fixed it.

I'm not sure if this works for Bedrock Edition, but it's worth a shot.